# Auto_increment table

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error after trying to import an SQL file:

> #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qbx_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext  
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Does anyone know what can be done? I don't understand much about SQL. Sorry and thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `meta_id` as primary key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qbx_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` LONGTEXT  
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72556/1)

Comment: Thank you! I still get the error!
I will try to study it deeper!

Comment: @Hans you can see [`demo here`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72556/1) may you have some other issue

Answer (score 1):

The auto_increment column needs to be a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qbx_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I tried that before, but still gives me the error:


#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key